# Symfony2 inject an array of services into a controller from config.yml

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection

How I can inject an array of services from config.yml giving class names (with namespaces) to a controller? I need to run a function from each of this services in the controller. At the moment I use `$this->get('service');` in the controller, but I need to make controller independent from services. Is there a way to do this?

#### Edit

I don't know names and how many services will be injected, though all of them implement an Interface.

#### Edit2

Well, probably I did not express correctly my thoughts. I have a bundle named Widgets. It has an array of widget names, display widget holders for each widget and with AJAX I get the content and display it. At the moment I have in the Widget controller hardcoded some widget deffinitions (title and id for Ajax) and some are retrieved by calling getWidgetList from some controllers from another bundle. Well I need that the list of the widgets wont be hardcoded itself in the widget bundle. I need a way to pass this list from the config.yml. Any ideas?

Comment: see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html and /or the bottom of the page http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html#avoiding-your-code-becoming-dependent-on-the-container

Comment: Have you looked at defining controllers as services? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html

Comment: Not positive what you are asking but you can use a compiler pass to dynamically build a service definition.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html

Comment: Even with your clarifications I still don't understand.  If you just need to pass an array of data then make a parameter.  Otherwise, consider pasting the code for one of your current controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Injecting an array of services is, generally speaking, not the right approach (even if there was a way to do it, which I don't think there is)

The whole reason you don't want to write container-dependent code is to keep your codebase flexible, lithe, and testable.  A variable array of services is, in practice, just a mini container, so if you implemented that you'd just be shrinking the scope of the problem, not eliminating it. You'd still be making your code dependent on an arbitrary bucket of services.

I strongly recommend explicitly defining each service your controllers need (as outlined by the links in the comments from Rufinus and Cerad) or look into using something like the [jms/di-extra-bundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle).

### Update

Maybe you need to do more research on the configuration options available?

- [How to Create Friendly Configuration for a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html)
- [The Config Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/introduction.html)

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html

Comment: I made an edit to my question trying to make myself more clear. The widgets are completely independent functionality except from WidgetBundle where I enter the list of them.

Comment: Added a few more links for you